# Countifs in Python with non equal join

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

I have been stuck with this problem for a long time and need help on this.

I have below Data in table T1 with 4 million rows.

I need to count in python based on below excel formula:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<"&B2,C:C,"<"&C2)`

```
Table Name -T1

User Id Start time  End time    Count  
A1  10-01-2018 10:15    10-01-2018 12:15    0  
A2  10-01-2018 10:45    10-01-2018 11:15    0  
A1  10-01-2018 10:25    10-01-2018 13:30    1  
A2  10-01-2018 11:00    10-01-2018 11:40    1
```

End Result is Count column

I have tried below methods and in both cases I am getting a memory error.

Is there any method to do this :

1. `pysqldf("SELECT T1.,count() FROM T1 a left join T1 b on a.user_id=b.user_id and a.start_time>b.start_time and a.end_time>b.end_time group by 1,2,3")`
2. merge and then filtering (python does not allow non equal join in merge)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd

fmt = '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M'
columns = ['Users', 'Start Time', 'End Time', 'Count']

df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheetname="Sheet1")
df.columns=columns

#get the start dates less than the first
df1=df[df['Start Time']<df.iloc[0]['Start Time']]
#get the end dates less than the first
df2=df[df['End Time']<df.iloc[0]['End Time']]

#find matching rows between df1 and df2
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=columns, how='inner')
print(df3)
```

I ran this on the data below

```
A1   10-01-2018 10:15   10-01-2018 12:15   0
A2   10-01-2018 10:45   10-01-2018 11:15   0 
A3   10-01-2018 10:25   10-01-2018 13:30   1
A4   10-01-2018 11:00   10-01-2018 11:40   1
A5   10-01-2018 10:00   10-01-2018 11:15   0
```

This prints:

```
  Users        Start Time          End Time  Count
0    A5  10-01-2018 10:00  10-01-2018 11:15      0
```

If you want this back in a python `dict` just use:

```
df3.set_index('Users').T.to_dict('dict')
#{'A5': {'Start Time': '10-01-2018 10:00', 'End Time': '10-01-2018 11:15','Count': 0}}
```

**edit**

I don’t have excel on my computer and I had trouble deciphering the excel formula. If the above code does what you want except constraining to a user, then place this just above where I define `df1` and `df2`. This constrains to a particular user.

```
df = df[df.Users == 'A1']
```

Then to get the count of all after these filters:

```
df3.shape()[0]
```

Comment: Hi Jaba,  Thanks for the answer however i required to compare each row to all rows with condition user_id to be equal, Start_time>all_row_start_time and Start_time<all_row_end_time as shown in formula :=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<"&B2,C:C,"<"&C2)

Comment: @user2021779 please see my edit. I’m headed to sleep, if you have further questions I will help tomorrow.